# Count number of character in a python list giving incorrect answer

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to calculate number characters in the following list but its giving incorrect answer. this is not working for this particular list.

```
words = [b'#Repost@motivated.mindset\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x83\xbb\'']
sum1=sum(len(i) for i in words)
print(sum1)
```

output is 37

but the correct answer is 68

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that the correct answer is `68`?

Comment: On Microsoft Word, it is giving word count as 68 also I counted manually.

Comment: @Kasramvd actaully len() function is not working as expected if you try for word. 
words = b'#Repost@motivated.mindset\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x83\xbb\''
len(words)

Comment: len is giving the correct byte count, not the number of characters in this encoded string representation as bytes

Comment: @Txema maybe is it because of an escape character. do you have any suggestion to find a number of characters? as in the Microsoft word

Comment: for me len(str(words[0])) is 67 and len(words[0]) is 36

Answer (score 1):

You have a bytes object, probably a utf-8 encoded string, you can count a lot of things: len(word) simply gives the number of bytes in this array.

But to write the bytes you use different notations, count one for ascii, two if escaped, and 4 chars for hexadecimal notation. It seems to be a utf-8 encoded string, one letter is more than one byte, so tell me what do you want to count.

```
word = b'#Repost@motivated.mindset\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x83\xbb\''
index = 0
codechars = 0
for number in word:
    index+=1
    b =  number.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')
    bs = len(str(b)[2:-1]) #b'' 
    codechars+=bs
    print("%2.0f" % index, repr(b).ljust(10-len(b)), len(b), bs, hex(number), number )

print("Byte count", index )

print(word)
print("code count", codechars )

print(word.decode("utf-8"))
print("utf-8 count", len(word.decode("utf-8")))

assert codechars==len(repr(word[2:-1]))
assert len(word)==index
```

Output:

```
...
25 b't'      1 1 0x74 116
26 b'\n'     1 2 0xa 10
27 b'\xe3'   1 4 0xe3 227
28 b'\x83'   1 4 0x83 131
29 b'\xbb'   1 4 0xbb 187
30 b'\xe3'   1 4 0xe3 227
31 b'\x83'   1 4 0x83 131
32 b'\xbb'   1 4 0xbb 187
33 b'\xe3'   1 4 0xe3 227
34 b'\x83'   1 4 0x83 131
35 b'\xbb'   1 4 0xbb 187
36 b"'"      1 1 0x27 39
Byte count 36
b"#Repost@motivated.mindset\n\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x83\xbb'"
code count 64
#Repost@motivated.mindset
・・・'
utf-8 count 30
```

Comment: Initially, I misunderstood len() function. It is simply giving the number of bytes but I want to measure a length of the string. your last comment solved an issue for me. Thank you very much